# number of Parenthesizations for fixed number of "()" pairs

Tags: algorithm, parentheses

Say we'd like to count the number of different parenthesizations of n pairs of brackets but having a fixed number of "()" pairs. How do we count these.

ex:
for n = 3. i.e 3 pairs of parenthesizations, if we want number of parenthizations with k = 2 pairs of "()"
the number of ways is 3.

()(())

(())()

(()())

for n = 4,k = 2, it will be 6

((()()))

()((()))

(())(())

(()(()))

((()))()

((())())

Comment: but Catalan gives the total ways to parenthesize n pairs of brackets. What i am looking for is special type of parenthesizations.
i.e having a fixed number of "()" pairs.
Have a look at the examples i've given.

Comment: I think there is a neat formula for this. I proposed something earlier but it was wrong. I'm working on it though.

Comment: even i guess so.
and ur previous answer provided a nice way to look at the problem.

Comment: @ShashankGupta why was it wrong? I looked at it for a while and it seemed okay, then I checked back later and it was deleted :(

Comment: @PherricOxide It was pointed out to me that my formula didn't work for cases like n==k or k==1 and several other cases as well. DSM had the right formula in his answer but I don't know how to prove his answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is [A001263](http://oeis.org/A001263), a.k.a. the Narayana numbers, and that the formula is

```
T(n,k) = C(n-1,k-1) C(n,k-1)/k with 1<=k<=n
```

One interpretation of A001263 is that T(n,k) is the number of Dyck n-paths with exactly k peaks, and you can interpret each Dyck step as either `(` or `)` and each peak as `()`.

Comment: Seems to the the correct answer.
Can u also please elaborate how do we get this ?
or can you let me know of a reference which explains how this closed form is found.